# How to substract exact timestamp minutes 00:15 in SQL for every day in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, timestamp

I am substracting daily values. For example, I got:

```
       timestamp           value
2020-03-23 00:00:00.000    3000
2020-03-23 00:15:00.000    3100
2020-03-24 00:00:00.000    3500
2020-03-24 00:15:00.000    4000
```

and with:

```
SELECT tagtimeutc,description,tagname,unit,
    (   (LEAD (TagValue) OVER (order by tag_id,TagTimeUTC) -
            TagValue)),prik_sifr,tag_id
    FROM vwDMData
    where TagTimeUTC=DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and unit='m3'
       or TagTimeUTC=DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0) and unit='m3'
```

I get:

```
    date      value
2020-03-23    500
```

but I want

```
    date      value
2020-03-23    900
```

(So that substraction is between 1d 00:15 values) like:

```
value(2020-03-24 00:15:00.000) - value(2020-03-23 00:15:00.000)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And your query uses columns not in the sample. Your result uses columns not in your query. Other columns are missing in the result. [Edit] the question and add a proper [example], i.e. the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. And tag the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the `where`:

```
SELECT tagtimeutc, description, tagname, unit,
       (LEAD(TagValue) OVER (order by tag_id,TagTimeUTC) -
        TagValue)
       ),
       prik_sifr, tag_id
FROM vwDMData
WHERE unit = 'm3' AND
      TagTimeUTC >= DATEADD(minute, -15, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as DATETIME)) AND
      TagTimeUTC < DATEADD(minute, 24*60-15, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as DATETIME)) ;
```

Comment: it returns: Msg 9810, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The datepart minute is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Comment: @bobialen . . . Use `CAST( GETDATE() as DATE)` to remove the time component.  Then `CAST( CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) as DATETIME)` to convert to a `datetime`.

Comment: I need answer that return value from date like value(2020-03-24 00:15:00.000) - value(2020-03-23 00:15:00.000)